# How to handle repetitive code dealing with object properties?

Tags: java, dry

Every so often I run into a situation where I need to map a set of properties from one object to another object of a different, unrelated class. The set of properties is large enough to make typing out the code by hand tedious. Anti-DRY principle code like this is the result:

```
if (objectOfType1.getPropertyA() != null){objectOfType2.setSimilarlyNamedPropertyA(someMethod(objectOfType1.getPropertyA()));}
if (objectOfType1.getPropertyB() != null){objectOfType2.setSimilarlyNamedPropertyB(someMethod(objectOfType1.getPropertyB()));}
...skipping some lines...
if (objectOfType1.getPropertyZ() != null){objectOfType2.setSimilarlyNamedPropertyZ(someMethod(objectOfType1.getPropertyZ()));}
```

Writing and even looking at code like this is a huge pet peeve, but I feel like using an introspection library like BeanUtils to avoid having a couple of methods like this would irritate my coworkers.

I've taken to writing one-off scripts to generate code like this for me. How have other programmers addressed this problem?

**Edit**: Here's the code translated to use reflection/introspection. Sure it's DRY, but it might make an enemy out of the next programmer on the project, and I can be just as productive generating code like above with a script. That said, if this is more common than I suspect, please fill me in:

```
    //Is this really a common technique to use when there's a simpler method?
    String[] propertyNamePartsArr = {"A","B", ...skipping some parts..., "Z"};
    List<String> propertyNameParts = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(propertyNamePartsArr));

    for (String propertyNamePart : propertyNameParts) {
        try {
            Object originalValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(objectOfType1, "property" + propertyNamePart);
            if (originalValue != null) {
                BeanUtils.setProperty(objectOfType2, "similarlyNamedProperty" + propertyNamePart, someMethod(originalValue));
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            handleIllegalAccessException(e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            handleInvocationTargetException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            handleNoSuchMethodException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not too familiar with Java, but why not just use reflection?  This is the sort of situation where it's very useful.

Comment: Are those properties coded by different developers ? are those properties always from objects already defined, or you can change those classes ?

Comment: Generally, I'm usually not free to change the classes, or at least not much. Usually when I find myself in situations like this I'm getting an object from some third-party API and performing a conversion to another object to use with a different third-party API. Say for example mapping from XML binding classes to a myBatis result map. Any modification to the first would be wiped out next time the XML changes and the class is regenerated. I could change the second but it would still need to have the expected properties with appropriate types.

Answer (score 3):

**You should be using [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).**

In your particular case you should create a map between methods of Type1 to methods of Type2 (if they always have the same name even better). Then using reflection you'll call `getPropertyA` in one object of Type1 and call the setter to put the value on the other object of Type2. It's very straight forward and this is a classic case where you need to use things at the [metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata#Metadata_types) level.

Comment: In Java 7 you might be able to use MethidHandles and MethodTypes instead, in theory a more type safe, security manager safe and faster way than Reflection, YMMV of course.

Comment: @MartijnVerburg I've heard of it but never really used it so I can't really vouch for it.